# Layout.xml store specific

Tags: magento-1.8, store-view, layout

I am trying to change the top links in the layout.xml base on the store

```
 <STORE_german>
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Sign Up</label><url>german-url</url><title>Sign Up</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>101</position><liParams>id="link-sign-up"</liParams>
        <aParams>
            <class>top-links-link</class>
        </aParams>
        </action>
       </reference>
   </customer_logged_out>
</STORE_german>
```

So here the only difference is that the url is now "german-url" however its not picking up. Could anyone advise where I am going wrong

Comment: what is mean by pickup?

Comment: Well the URL is still /customer/account/create/ when it should be /german-url

Comment: As per Magento standard  it is not good change the url like as german url because when you call customer Module account controller and create method so if you change the url then it's not good

Answer (score 1):

try this

Magento do `not provide to change to  label,title,url etc  of a top lin`k.So need

remove old link by  **removeLinkByUrl** function 
then add  as **new link as it is possible to update a top links   url**

```
    <STORE_default>

      <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /></action>

       <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Sign Up test</label>
                <url>german-url</url>
                <title>Sign Up test test</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>101</position>
                <liParams>id="link-sign-up"</liParams>
                <aParams>
                <class>top-links-link</class>
                </aParams>
                </action>
     </reference>

</STORE_default>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `Magento standards` It is not good to change the URL structure like

`/Kunden/Konto/create/` instead of `/customer/account/create/`

Because when you call this URL then `/customer/account/create/`

`customer` is `Module` .

`account` is `controller` .

`create` is `method` .

so if you change the url then it's not good. when you change one language to another language then Magento automatically create query sting and based on that it will detect store language and based on translate whole page.

Comment: I understand where your coming from but from an SEO point of view its better to have the native language than English for the url segments

Comment: As per SEO we think then if you have e-commerce store then you more focus on product SEO rather then login, logout, create page it's magneto by default feature y you want to change this

Comment: As I said I agree but if the whole site is in German and then there are 4 links in English it looks odd

Comment: then you have to override the module of customer and change the url key in that as per your need